# C# find Min in an array for NinjaScript

Tags: c#, arrays, min

I am new to coding, and I am trying to write some code for NinjaScript / NinjaTrader in C#, and I hope someone can help. 
I have a variable “tovBullBar” which calculates some values for a certain type of price bar within a three minute period. More than one of these bars may occur in that period. The values are all calculated correctly and I can see them in the output window. I am trying to use an array to identify the bar with the Min calculated value in that period, so that the value may be included in my final calculation of netLvtTOV. However, my final calculation keeps ending up with the last “tovBullBar” value in the period rather than the one with Min value. Could you please have a look at my code to see if you can tell me where I am going wrong?

I have coded for up to 10 elements in the array, but they almost certainly will be lower and will vary in each 3 minute period. Having looked at some posts here I suppose I should be using a dynamic List (which I’ll have to get my head around later), but see no reason why it shouldn’t work with an array as long as the number of elements I define are more than I’ll need.

Thanks!

```
#region Using declarations
using System;
using System.Linq;
#endregion

#region Variables
//Declare an array that will hold data for tovBullBar
private double[] tovBull;
private int length = 10;
#endregion

protected override void Initialize()
{
    //specify the number of elements in the array, which is the
    integer called length
    tovBull = new double[length];
}

protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{
    //the array now contains the number length of object references that need to be set to instances of objects
   for (int count = 0; count<length; count++)
       tovBull[count]=tovBullBar;

   //Do a for loop to find the minimum for the tovBull
   double tovBullBarMin = tovBull[0];

   for (int count = 0; count < tovBull.Length; count++)
       if (tovBullBarMin > tovBull[count]) 
           tovBullBarMin = tovBull[count];  

   netLvtTOV = Math.Round((tovBearBar + tovBullBarMin + lvtBullBar)
   Print (Time.ToString()+" "+"ArrayLength:"+tovBull.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this bit of code at the start of your `OnBarUpdate` method:

```
for (int count = 0; count<length; count++)
    tovBull[count]=tovBullBar;
```

this sets all members of the array to the same value.

Then you iterate over the same array to find the one with the lowest value.

```
for (int count = 0; count < tovBull.Length; count++)
   if (tovBullBarMin > tovBull[count]) 
       tovBullBarMin = tovBull[count];
```

so of course they all will wind up with the same value...

I think that what you want to do at the start of the method is 'push' the latest value into the array before you  find the latest value by simply shuffling them all along by one in the array and then adding the latest to the front of the array:

```
for (int count = 1; count<length; count++)
    tovBull[count]= tovBull[count - 1];

tovBull[0] = tovBullBar;
```

Notice, that, since you did not initialise the `tovBull` array elements they will all be zero to start with. So you might have to do something like this:

```
tovBull = new double[length];

for (int i = 0; i < tovBull.Length; i++)
    tovBull[i] = double.MaxValue;
```

then the comparisons at the end will give you the right result.

If you are having problems looking at values only in the last n minutes, you have to do a little bit more work.

First you need to have a little class that keeps track of time and value:

```
private class BarEvent
{
    public readonly DateTime Time;
    public readonly double Value;

    public BarEvent(double value)
    {
       Value = value;
       Time = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of having tovBull as a an array of double you change it to:

```
List<BarEvent> tovBull = new List<BarEvent>();
```

and change OnBarUpdate as follows:

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{
   // first remove all items more than 3 minutes old
   DateTime oldest = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
   tovBull.RemoveAll(be => be.Time < oldest);

   // add the latest value
   tovBull.Add(new BarEvent(tovBullBar));

   //Find the minimum for the tovBull using linq
   double tovBullBarMin = tovBull.Min(be => be.Value);

  netLvtTOV = Math.Round((tovBearBar + tovBullBarMin + lvtBullBar)
  Print (Time.ToString()+" "+"ArrayLength:"+tovBull.Count);
}
```

Comment: I have used the lines of coding you have suggested, and they have helped to assign the correct array values to my final calculation. But I am still having one main problem. Where a TOVBullBar does not appear in the 3 minute period after the first signal, instead of assigning a value of 0 for tovBullBarMin in the final computation, the code looks back to periods before the start of the 3 mins and picks up the last tovBullBar value to use in the calculation. I have tried to use Array.Clear at the end of the 3min to stop this, but not working. Will try to post code.

Comment: Line after the firstsig:                                                                              `if (check && Time[0] < firstSig.AddMinutes(3))`                                 Line after other signals within 3mins and netLvtTOV calculation:          `if (check && Time[0] >= firstSig.AddMinutes(3))
   {
   Array.Clear(tovBull,0,tovBull.Length);
   Print(Time[0] + " Final Signal.");
   check = false;`

Comment: how do I define the BarEvent which starts the 3 min clock, as this only starts after a lvtBullBar? At present it seems to be counting all bars, so the ArrayLength is 800+, when for each block of 3 mins it should be no more than up to say 7 max if just counting the tovBullBars. Thanks!

Comment: @ Übercoder, I have now got it to work using arrays by zeroing the tovBullBar after clearing the array, like so: `Array.Clear(tovBull,0,10);` and  `tovBullBar = 0;` Thanks for the help!